# quote in csv file to import into MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, csv, mysql-workbench

Using MySQL on Mac OSX and execute SQL using MySQL Workbench, here is the SQL query and content of csv file, I want to input string with quote, for example, I want to input `f"o"o`, I tried to use `f\"o\"o`, but seems not working, any ideas how to import with quote for a column in csv file?

**SQL Query**,

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/Users/foo/Downloads/import.csv' 
INTO TABLE tasks 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

**Table schema**,

```
create database exercise;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tasks (
  task_id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  subject VARCHAR(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  start_date DATE DEFAULT NULL,
  end_date DATE DEFAULT NULL,
  description VARCHAR(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (task_id)
```

**CSV file content**,

```
1,"hello/world",,,"f\"o\"o"
2,"hello/world",,,"g\"o\"o"
3,"hello/world",,,"z\"o\"o"
```

**Content after import**,

```
SELECT * FROM exercise.tasks;
```

[image]

**Edit 1**,

Tried to use double quote to encode quote, tried this way, after import still the same as the screen snapshot I posted.

```
1,"hello/world",,,"f""o""o"
2,"hello/world",,,"g""o""o"
3,"hello/world",,,"z""o""o"
```

**Edit 2**, tried this but not working, (after import, it is `foo` other than f`o`o)

```
1,"hello/world",,,f'o'o
2,"hello/world",,,g'o'o
3,"hello/world",,,z'o'o
```

**Edit 3**, tried this and also not working, (after import, it is `foo` other than f`o`o)

```
1,"hello/world",,,"f''o''o"
2,"hello/world",,,"g'o''o"
3,"hello/world",,,"z''o''o"
```

**Edit 4**, warning I see,

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/Users/foo/Downloads/import.csv'  INTO TABLE tasks  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','  ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '\\' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'  3 row(s) affected, 6 warning(s): 1265 Data truncated for column 'start_date' at row 1 1265 Data truncated for column 'end_date' at row 1 1265 Data truncated for column 'start_date' at row 2 1265 Data truncated for column 'end_date' at row 2 1265 Data truncated for column 'start_date' at row 3 1265 Data truncated for column 'end_date' at row 3 Records: 3  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 6
```

regards,
Lin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The doubling of the enclosing char really should work. Maybe there is a different problem that makes your import fail? Check also with the raw text output (`Query -> Execute .. to Text`) or with the command line client.

Alternatively, you could use a different enclosing character. What about using a single quote instead? If you don't have commas in your text (i.e. the char used as field terminator) you can entirely omit the enclosing character (since the field terminator would be enough to separate entries in this case).

Comment: Hi Mike, I tried your method of `Query -> Execute .. to Text` and also tried to remove double quote at beginning and end, but neither way works. I post Edit 2 and Edit 3, I also notice a warning, posted there and not sure if it is related to this issue?

You mentioned command line client? Do you mean some tools to import csv file or just execute SQL query?

Comment: BTW, if you try my posted simple import.csv file, does it work for you?

Comment: Thanks Mike, I have figured out there is an issue at my side, I fixed it then your solution works. Mark your reply as answer and vote up.

Answer (score 1):

You should double the double quotes to escape them: `f""o""o`

[MySQL Doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html):

> To avoid ambiguity, occurrences of the ENCLOSED BY character within a
>   field value can be doubled and are interpreted as a single instance of
>   the character.

Comment: Hi Scarabee, tried your method not working, see my update Edit 1 section.